# Python - concatenate a string to itself, multiple times

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have a string `my_string = "I am good."`

How can I get a string that contains three copies of `my_string`, with spaces in between? Would it be something like `str.join(' ',my_string*3)`?

Answer (score 21):

You're pretty close.  Try this:

```
>>> my_string = "I am good."
>>> " ".join([my_string]*3)
'I am good. I am good. I am good.'
```

You need `[my_string]*3` instead of `my_string*3` because you want a list containing the string three times (that can then be joined) instead of having a single big string containing the message three times.

Also, `" ".join(a)` is shorthand for `str.join(" ", a)`.

Answer (score 3):

`" ".join([my_string for i in range(3)]`

Answer (score 3):

I ran some perfomance checks, to see how different methods compete with each other.

Results:

```
For loop: 5.720043182373047
List join: 0.8931441307067871
String multiplication: 0.025591611862182617
```

Code used:

```
import time

def forLoop(s):
  start = time.time()
  z = ""
  for i in range(ITERS):
    z += s
  return time.time()-start

def listJoin(s):
  start = time.time()
  "".join([s]*ITERS)
  return time.time()-start

def strMultiply(s):
    start = time.time()
    s*ITERS
    return time.time()-start

ITERS = 10000
my_string = "I am good."
a, b, c = 0, 0, 0
for i in range(ITERS):
    a += forLoop(my_string)
    b += listJoin(my_string)
    c += strMultiply(my_string)

print("For loop:", a)
print("List join:", b)
print("String multiplication:", c)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
" ".join((my_string,) * 3)
```

Comment: Actually, I think you want something like `" ".join((my_string,)*3)`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just take advantage of the fact that multiplying a string concatenates copies of it: add a space to the end of your string and multiply without using `join`.

```
>>> my_string = "I am good."
>>> (my_string+' ')*3
'I am good. I am good. I am good. '
```

Comment: Nice, but this string has an extra space.